# Outer product of vectors of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say there are two matrices

$A = \begin{pmatrix}   
a11 & a12 \\
a21 & a22 
\end{pmatrix} $

$B = \begin{pmatrix}   
b11 & b12 \\
b21 & b22 
\end{pmatrix} $

Is there a (or a series of) mathematical operation(s) I can do that would give me outer products of the two columns of $A$ with 2 rows of $B$ (respectively) such that I get two $2x2$ matrices with following output?

$AB1 = \begin{pmatrix}   
a11b11 & a11b12 \\
a21b11 & a21b12 
\end{pmatrix} $

$AB2 = \begin{pmatrix}   
a12b21 & a12b22 \\
a22b21 & a22b22 
\end{pmatrix} $

In the end I would like to sum $AB1$ and $AB2$ to get a single $2x2$ matrix, is there any straightforward method to do this?

Comment: Maybe the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) is involved? See the $2\times 2$-examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definitions that you've given, it holds that $$AB1 + AB2 = AB,$$ the standard product two matrices.

Comment: Oh I am so stupid. Thank you so much! Sorry my upvote doesn't count. I initially tried matrix product but did some calculation mistake and rejected the idea, and have been sitting clueless since. This is a new way to think of matrix product and I think it would even work for any matrix shapes and sizes. Is there also any intuitive explanation for why this works?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal, you can accept the answer by pressing the tick next to where the voting arrows are. In general you could always split your matrix product into a sum over different terms. In higher dimensions there will be more than two terms. I would take this as the definition for the matrix product, which you could motivate in terms of linear maps if you wanted an intuition for this definition. The full product transforms covariantly under change of basis but the individual terms don't, so I don't think you'll find them useful to work with in most applications.